Synapse rtrim removes trailing spaces but not when substring length is defined and even its a trailing space it will not trim till that range?
I am reading the data from feed and then distributing accordingly using derived column But issue seems to be the trailing space gets deleted after range ends for example
columnID rtrim(column_1, 45,25) it will start reading from 45 till 25 character but even my file had space and it only reads 18 character but it will not remove space till 25 character ??
I tried one more logice reverse(ltrim(reverse((column_1, 45,25))) this also seems to be not working properly ??
Any idea how we can achive this in derived column or is it possible while sink mapping ???
Example input:
string return after rtrm " IOM APPLICATION
"
But I need just " IOM APPLICATION"

rtrim(rtrim(substring,(column1,45,25)))  will nested rtrim will work ???

The expression doesn't have substring function itself. The correct expression should look like, rtrim(substring(column_1, 45,25)). This would first take the substring from the column_1 and then trims the trailing whitespaces.
rtrim() will have 2 parameters. If second parameter is not specified, it trims the whitespace from the string. Otherwise, it trims the value specified in the second parameter.
If rtrim(substring(column_1, 45,25)) expression is not trimming the characters, then that may not be the whitespace character. You can copy those characters and paste it as a second parameter in the rtrim function. The expression will look like,
rtrim(substring(column_1, 45,25),'<character-to-be-trimmed>')
Replace <character-to-be-trimmed> with the correct value in the above expression.


Str= "  APPLE     "   rtrimsubstring(0,12) ==> "  APPLE     " it should be " APPLE" but synapse is not returning that output in posgrace sql

What are you getting in postgresql? share the screenshot
